# Using libraries other than PyQGIS to develop plugin for QGIS?

Tags: python, qgis-plugins, shapely, pyqgis-3, fiona

I develop a plugin for QGIS. Before to integreted it in the QGIS I developped it with GIS library (Fiona, shapely, geopandas, ...) and it work well. Now I try to build it with plugin_builder of QGIS. The problem is I try to use my functions that I created with the previous libraries, but it seems like PyQGIS (QGIS) didn't recongnize them.

Is it possible to work with the GIS libraries to open, write a vector and make some processes in QGIS environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use those librairies in a qgis plugin as long as you install them on the folder sites-packages of the python called by qgis.

use OsGeo4W Shell to install them ( I use pip for that )
then you can call them from your plugin, also make sure that `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH` environment variables are well set.

Comment: Doesn't that (using other library) make it harder to share the plugin ?

Comment: @J.R I don't see the problem if the dependencies of the plugin are present in a requirements.txt file

Comment: If it's possible to use only PyQGIS then other don't have to install other library to use the plugin, not a big deal but easier for novice

Comment: yes, indeed it would be easier, it depends if OP wants to share his plugin online or not

Comment: Thanks @HichamZouarhi for your answers. Yeah, J.R you are right, using only PyQGIS will make easier to install use the plugin, but for the moment i already finished it and i have use other libraries, and also i think Fiona and shapely are more easialy to use than PyQGIS. This is my opinion ;)